# Chrome speech recognition recognize Arabic on Windows 7 but not on Android

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, speech-recognition

I am adding a link to my server to make it easy to view my code and to run it on any device:

http://od123.site90.com/sr_test/sr_test01.html

The code is for speech recognition. It was taken from:

http://shapeshed.com/html5-speech-recognition-api/

I had managed to run this sample on Windows 7:

I added a line:

```
recognition.lang = "ar-QA"; // "en-GB"; "he";
```

And it actually translate speech to text for English and Arabic and Hebrew!!

But only on Windows 7...

On my Galaxy tablet - only English works.

On my Galaxy S4 - English and Hebrew works - but Arabic does not.

1. Is there a known diff between Android and Windows Chrome Speech Recognition?
2. A matter of Android device setup?
3. Any idea how to make this example recognize Arabic on Android?

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial solution.

Arabic speech recognition works for me now once I change my tablet setting:
In Setting->Control->Language and Input->Google voice typing:
I unchecked all lang and checked Arabic Qatar

I did not manage to make the JS:
recognition.lang = "ar-QA";
works.